# TensforflowJS nodejs binding, unable to set custom optimzer

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm just getting started with tensorflowjs and tensorflow in general and I've run into an issue I can't quite solve. I'm trying to change the learning rate for an optimizer, but as soon a I use a custom optimizer I receive the following error:

`User-defined optimizer must be an instance of tf.Optimizer`

to create my model I'm doing the following (lifted from the docs [here](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/index.html#data.csv)):

```
const model = tf.sequential();
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units:1, inputShape:[11]}));
  model.compile({
    optimizer: tf.train.sgd(0.000001),
    loss: 'meanSquaredError'
  });
```

so as far as I can see everything should work. And if I just pass in the default 'sgd' optimzer it does indeed work.

```
model.compile({loss:'meanSquaredError', optimizer:'sgd'});
```

and the docs at https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/index.html#train.sgd also imply the first code snippet should be returning an SGDOptimizer.

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I'm running node V8 with the following tensorflow package

```
"@tensorflow/tfjs-core": "^0.14.2",
"@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^0.1.21",
```

If I create my optimzer and store it in a separate variable. A console.log of that var gives the following:

```
SGDOptimizer {
  learningRate: 0.000001,
  c: 
   Tensor {
     isDisposedInternal: false,
     shape: [],
     dtype: 'float32',
     size: 1,
     strides: [],
     dataId: {},
     id: 4,
     rankType: '0' } }
```

So it appears it is initialized

Comment: Are you using a particular node js binding ? If not you can consider removing the tfjs-node binding

Comment: I wasn't using a particular binding, I was just under the impression it was needed to run under a server side environment rather than in the browser. But even when removing that it still doesn't work

Comment: Here you have a working code using tf.train.sgd: https://repl.it/@kedevked/tensorflowjs-with-node

Comment: even with your model code I get exactly the same error

Comment: The code is running. I don't see any error. Could you please give a link with your code which outputs the error ?

Comment: Even if I just copy and past your exact code in a new file I get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't import tfjs-core in your package.json directly. If you import tfjs-node alone, it will import the proper tfjs-core version.

The issue is you have a double dependency (which we will fix).

Comment: Ah ok thanks, not sure why I had the double dependency, maybe it's because I installed the main package and then the  core so followed multiple install instructions. Although now if I just try and install @tensorflow/tfjs-node I get an error...Cannot find module 'https-proxy-agent' - though installing that separately seems to have worked

Comment: In the next release you'll only have to add the tfjs-node package as your dependency and require tf through it. Here is the PR that fixes this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-node/pull/187